# List of unknown generic types or invoke a generic subclass

Tags: c#, generics

I want a list with objects with generic type parameters. Is this possible?
I can't do this because T isn't known in the containing class:

```
private List<GenericClass<T>> list = new List<GenericClass<T>>();
```

So I tried to make an abstract base class list, but then I have no way to invoke the method that used the the generic parameter:

```
private List<BaseGenericClass> list = new List<BaseGenericClass>();

void DoSomething(string data)
{
    var baseGeneric = list.First();
    baseGeneric.SomeGenericMethod<T>(data); //<- SomeGenericMethod isn't known in the base class
}
```

and I don't see a way to cast it to the subclass to be able to use the method. Is something like this even possible without reflection? If reflection is the only option, what is the performance penalty on that?

Thanks

**EDIT**
The use case is I have a websocket connection that can send me different events. In advance I can subscribe different event handler for the different events. These events are json objects which I deserialize to different objects depending on the event type. I would like to provide these event handlers with the specific type the event Throws; T.

Comment: You can only call methods that are defined in the base class. If SomeGenericMethod isn't in BaseGenericClass then you can't use it like this. If all classes have this method then put it in the base class?

Comment: Are you looking for OfType<T>()?

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear to me also it seems that you didn't understand what a generic parameter is. If you want to use a generic parameter somewhere you have to define this parameter first, either on the method or the class. This also includes code paths depending on the aforementioned method or class. So to apply this on your code examples: you don't have `T` defined therefore you can't use it.

Comment: The problem is that the calling class/method doesn't know what T is. For OfType<T> I need T at compile time while I only know it at run time. I can't put the method in the base class because then I can't make a list of those classes. (see the initial code block)

Comment: @JanKorf , while I am not completely sure what you're trying to do. Since the type is not known at compile time anyway you might just as well switch to using *dynamic* - you are trying to call a method by name, which you assume to know,  on a type you clearly don't know.

Comment: Unless these runtime types have a common base/interface which you do know about - then this might be a job for *generic constraints*